# C# - Method of programmatically attempting to check for memory leak in block of code

Tags: c#, .net, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

I'm trying to see how feasible it is to attempt to accurately determine that there is a potential memory leak in a block of managed .NET code programmatically. The reason to do this would be to isolate some block of code that appears to be leaking memory, and to then use a standard profiler to further determine the actual cause of the leak. In my particular business case, I would be loading a 3rd party class that extends one of mine to check it for leaks.

The approach that first comes to mind is something like this:

- Wait for GC to run.
- Get the current allocated memory from the GC.
- [Run block of managed code.]
- Wait for GC to run.
- Get the current allocated memory from the GC and subtract from the allocated memory recorded before running the block of code. Is it correct that the difference should theoretically be (near) 0 if all objects allocated in the block of code that was run were dereferenced appropriately and collected?

Certainly the immediate issue with this is that there will likely be waiting...and waiting...and waiting for the non-deterministic GC to run. If we skip that aspect, the calculation for determining if the block of code leaked any memory however can vary wildly, and would not necessarily be accurate, as some items may not have been collected at the time.

Does the above seem like my best option of attempting to determine somewhat accurately if a block of code is leaking memory? Or are there other working methods that are used in real-life? Thanks.

Comment: FYI you can force garbage collection by calling `GC.Collect()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Personally, I would never dare to do memory profiling on my own. I'll fear that I either do not have the full knowledge and that it would take endless time to do so.

Instead I used successfully memory profilers like [Red Gate's ANTS Memory Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/).

Comment: isn't Redgate the company that now charge for reflector after promising it would always be free. Fool me once Redgate, shame on you, fool me twice.....

Comment: @Tim I was almost sure about that this comment will come :-) Nonetheless that ANTS Memory Profiler is a superb tool for me, so I'll keep using ILSPY and still buy some Red Gate products.

Comment: :-) I was only half joking about Redgate, I may look at their profiler. But the reflector business really did leave a bad taste in my mouth. And its not about the money, it was just the principle of how they went about it. I now use ILSPY as well, its fine, whats more its helping me with learning Git as well :-)

Answer (score 1):

While using ANTS Profiler is awesome it doesn't help if your problem is only seen in production.

[Tess Ferrandez](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/) has a series of [Labs](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2008/02/04/net-debugging-demos-information-and-setup-instructions.aspx) that demonstrate how to debug production problems, including memory leaks. They focus on ASP.NET but it can be use for other types of applications as well.

Comment: [This one](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2008/02/15/net-debugging-demos-lab-3-memory.aspx) of her articles refers to memory issues. Sounds great!

Answer (score 0):

You really need a [Memory Profiler like this one](http://memprofiler.com/): With that, you can:

- start your application, take a memory snapshot (manually or from your code)
- [Run block of managed code]
- take another memory snapshot
- compare the two snapshots and see which new objects are now on the managed heap

I believe it does exactly what you want to do, only far less painful. It also has some helpful filters like "show objects that are kept alive by delegates". It can also analyze memory dumps from a production system.